# How to open an attachment straight from an InfoPath Form?

Tags: infopath, attachment

I would like to open an attachment directly from an InfoPath form, if possible.

I notice when viewing an InfoPath form in a web browser, I click the blue paperclip attachment icon, I am given three options—Attach, Download, and Remove (see screen [shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vEKN.png)). Yet when I open an InfoPath form in InfoPath's Preview environment, I get more options—Attach, Open, Save As, and Remove (see screen [shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71DjO.png)). Is there anyway to get this "Open" option available in the web browser?

Edit: Or perhaps there is a way to get the attachment's base64 encoded string programmatically? Does the File Attachment control have any kind of click event? I know I could add a button, use the button's click event and grab the base64 string that way, but I don't want to add any additionally UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the attachement control has a click event, only the button.

Also, keep in mind that for the WEB version, even though you can grab the value of the attachment field (base64 encoded as you said) you won't be able to write it locally or spawn a process to "open" it unless the form has full trust.

The signing and/or install needed for full trust over the web is by far more complicated than the code to get the field value and save/open it. Don't forget to evaluate that aspect before spending too much time on a solution.